# Continuous Web Job stops even if Always On is enabled

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have created an Azure Web App on Standard Service Plan with Always On option enabled. On this App I haven't published any web site. I have only published a Continuous Web Job.

The problem is that although I have enabled the Always On option, I can see in the Web Job logs that the Web App stopped.

Here are the Web Job logs:

```
[09/29/2015 07:35:26 > 189701: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[09/29/2015 08:51:54 > 189701: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
[09/29/2015 08:51:54 > 189701: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[09/29/2015 08:52:04 > 189701: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[09/29/2015 08:52:25 > 189701: SYS INFO] Run script 'ExchangePullNotifications.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[09/29/2015 08:52:25 > 189701: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I use the Azure SDK in my application which is not supported in the WebApp environment.

Comment: Hi Manos, what do you mean by "Azure SDK" is not supported? Thanks

Comment: @Marconline This is the answer I received from Microsoft, but over two years have passed since then and I don't think that this is still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening multiple times, or just that one time? If anything causes the site to restart (e.g. changes to the site settings), then this behavior is normal. It should have no ill effect as long as it restarts quickly after.

A concern would only exist if it was to stop and not restart, and that should not happen.

Comment: It has happened once since now. I am monitoring it to see if it happens again.

Comment: I can confirm that this happened again without any obvious reason.

Comment: Can you share your site name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: I have opened a support ticket to Azure and they are already investigating this. Thanks anyway!