# WebApp and supported WebJob SDK

Tags: azure-webjobssdk

My contnuous webjob stops after some time. I understand that potential reason for this could be because the WebJob SDK used to create webjob may not be supported by webapp. See [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32844626/continuous-web-job-stops-even-if-always-on-is-enabled)

I am using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (Version: 1.1.0-beta1(Prerelease) nuget package to create my webjob.

Is this SDK supported in WebApp?My WebApp is deployed in a ResourceGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the WebJobs SDK is fully supported in the Web Apps - that's the primary hosting scenario for the SDK.

As David mentioned in the other post, there are times when it is expected that your job will restart (site setting changes, file changes, etc.) If the restarts you're seeing aren't expected due to any of those reasons, then you'll want to check error logs to see what errors in your application might be causing this.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any useful information in logs. In fact, log says that webjob is still running. However, there is no processing. As David suggested , providing the webjob URL - https://amsdevappsvcwebapp.scm.amsdevappsvc.p.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/RegistrationPluginTest . Would appreciate if you could investigate.