# Webjob on azure not running continuously even when Always on option is ON

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am having a continuous Webjob which works fine for a couple of hours and then does not work until I restart. It seems to me azure takes it to idle mode but it shows me it's running but doesn't actually run. I have set the Always on option ON. I am having a paid plan with Azure. Do I need to use a timer or thread delay or some doughy code to keep it alive in my code? If that's the case whats the purpose of continuous option in webjob.

Comment: Is this happening multiple times, or just one time?

Comment: Someone use the Azure SDK in application which is not supported in the WebApp environment cause this problem, you could refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32844626/continuous-web-job-stops-even-if-always-on-is-enabled?rq=1).

Comment: I am not using azure ask. And it happens Daily.

Comment: Any chance that your continuous job executable is terminating on its own? Continuous WebJobs need to have forever loops.

Comment: Thank you David. That means I need to add a Thread or timer to keep it awake.

Comment: I think David refers to that your code needs to have a forever loop  e.g  https://imagebin.ca/v/47Nlx1aNEgcn

Comment: Does the webjob logs say anything on why it terminates? Here is a goog blog about the logging options - https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/03/14/azure-webjob-logs-demystified/

Comment: No it doesnot say anything.

Comment: I had this issue, it was an error I was eating in a try catch - I also found loop/forever webjobs tend to fail over time (hang), so moved to a cron trigger which executes once per trigger. Good luck with the webjob dark arts...

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide some documentation to back up the below comments you can have a look of the article here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#webjob-types

It provides the following information in regards to *Continuous WebJobs*:
*Starts immediately when the WebJob is created. **To keep the job from ending, the program or script typically does its work inside an endless loop.** If the job does end, you can restart it.*

I have outlined the part relevant to your question

Hope this helps provide some clarity

Cheers,
Lachie